# Is MLP a right DL algorithm for URL classification?

Tags: algorithm, deep-learning, mlp

I am new in machine learning, I am now working on a project using deep learning. the project works with texts, more specifically it is a URL binary classification.
I use python as a language and pycharm as an IDE, I am now advised to apply multi layer perceptron MLP algorithm but, I am not sure if this is the right algorithm for my work to apply or not.
any advice is appreciated.
best regards..

I am looking for an advice before starting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLP can indeed be used for your url binary classification, before that you need to turn your text data into something that a neural network can recognize. You can also use CNN, etc. for text classification, you can refer to:

[Keras_Multi_Label_TextClassfication](https://github.com/gezimonkey/Keras_Multi_Label_TextClassfication)